# java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I am trying to run Scala application using docker. I've created a sample project with the following structure.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version = 0.13.15
```

**src/main/scala/HelloWorld.scala**

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

Now if I do `sbt run`, everything works fine and I have the lovely hello-world greeting.

```
$ sbt run
...
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/Users/yuchen/Documents/test/)
[info] Running HelloWorld 
Hello, world!
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 22-May-2017 4:30:28 PM
```

I aded a **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM  openjdk:8

ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.12.2
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.15

RUN touch /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/release

RUN \
  curl -fsL http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz | tar xfz - -C /root/ && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

WORKDIR /root

CMD sbt run
```

They are all copied from https://hub.docker.com/r/hseeberger/scala-sbt/~/dockerfile/ and with the additional last line `CMD sbt run`.

And I tried running docker commands:

```
docker build -t test . 
docker tag test test/test:1.0
docker run test/test:1.0
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/root/)
[info] Updating {file:/root/}root...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 23, 2017 4:00:19 AM
```

**What does it mean and how do I resolve this?**

---

FYI: I am aware of http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html, but just want to try writing Dockerfile as I am learning this.

Comment: Your debugging output doesn't make sense to me. Are those actually the commands used? The output from the container is saying that it can't find `sbt.version` in the `build.properties` file at `/Users/yuchen/Documents/test/`. But the `Dockerfile` doesn't copy anything into any folder and the run command doesn't mount any volume. The error should show `file:/root/` instead.

Comment: Hey @AndyShinn Sorry I was trying random things and one of them was changing the `/root` to my actual work dir. Apparently, that didn't solve the problem. I've ran the commands again with `WORKDIR /root` and updated the output log. Any thoughts or suggestions what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know sbt. But this appears that you are not copying the project into the image (there is no `COPY` or `ADD` in the `Dockerfile`).

Try doing something like:

```
FROM  openjdk:8

ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.12.2
ENV SBT_VERSION 0.13.15

RUN touch /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/release

RUN \
  curl -fsL http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz | tar xfz - -C /root/ && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo 'export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc

RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

WORKDIR /myapp

CMD sbt run

COPY . /myapp
```

The addition here is just a `COPY` to copy all the code to `/myapp` and to changing the working directory to this folder as well. This would copy the build context to `/myapp` and then the `WORKDIR` should run `sbt run` from the same folder.

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what the problem was! Do you know why `COPY . /myapp` doesn't have to be before `CMD sbt run`?

Comment: The `CMD` is just setting the default command to run when starting a container based on this image. It isn't actually running anything at build time so it doesn't matter where it appears in the `Dockerfile`.